# Is it necessary to connect to a postgresql database in order to create a new server?

Tags: postgresql, python

I am writing a script in python 3.7, using psycopg2 to set up a new database from scratch. In all the tutorials I have seen, using psycopg2 starts by connecting to a database and getting a cursor object that can then be used to execute psql commands.

Example:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres", user="postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id serial PRIMARY KEY, num integer, data varchar);")
```

Is it necessary to connect to a database on one server in order to create a new server using psql (and psycopg2) or can you create a server first and then connect to it?

Answer (score 1):

You always have to connect to a database to run `CREATE DATABASE`. This is the main raison d'être for the `postgres` database.

There is the `createdb` executable that does this for you automatically.

Comment: Is there something similar for creating a new server?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "server"? To create a PostgreSQL cluster, you need to get shell access to the machine (or write an application that does it for you).

Comment: I mean to use the `CREATE SERVER` call, as defined here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createserver.html to create a new server that the script can then connect to and create databases and tables on.

Comment: Ah. But that is a foreign server, i.e. a connection to an already existing data source via foreign data wrapper. You cannot create databases via foreign data wrapper. Maybe you should edit the question and say what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I was trying to achieve a new server, but as it seems that is not possible, my question is answered. Could you please elaborate on the `createdb` executable? Where is it? Maybe a link to documentation? Thanks!

Comment: `createdb` creates a new database on an existing server, so it won't help you. You need to get shell access to the machine and install PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But in the case someone else reads this, or for myself at a later point, you suggested the `createdb` executable for the database creation. I was just wondering if that still needs you to connect first or not. That is, if it's a method on `connect` or `cursor` or how you would call it in a python file. I don't see how it would help with the connection if you still have to connect and get a cursor in order to use it.

Comment: No, you need shell access to invoke the executable `createdb`. Via a client connection, you run the SQL statement `CREATE DATABASE`.